# Display grid style

Tags: php, html, css

i have a select query on may database

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from items"))){
//here
}
```

i want it to display a grid style, and im using the

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from "))){
?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $row['path']?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

but it will display a vertical style, what html tag will i use, i also use the `<span>` but i cant display it correctly

Comment: In order to display them horizontally just remove `</tr><tr>` that makes the line change.

Answer (score 1):

In that case much better to wrap output of row in a function.
Smth like the following:

```
function showRow($row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $row['path']?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?
}
```

And then:

```
<table>
<?
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from "))){
    showRow($row);
}
?>
</table>
```